# Powershell: Passing a `Read-Host` as the key to HashTable

Tags: powershell, hashtable, user-input

I am trying to pass user input to hashTable, which I am attempting to do.

```
$someHash = 
@{
    1 = "one";
    2 = "two";
    3 = "three"
 }
 $x = Read-Host "enter 1,2,3"
 Write-Output($someHash.$x)
```

For some reason `$someHash.$x` and `$someHash[$x]` return null, but `$x` has it value.

I also can get values out of the map when I hard code keys. Not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

Adding to address comments.
I have also tried casting with the same result.

```
$someHash.[int]$x 
$someHash[[int]$x]
[int]$x = Read-Host "enter 1,2,3"
```

I have also used strings as keys using single and double-quotes. Same outcome.

Comment: you're trying to reference an `int`, with value of type `string`. Cast `[int]` to your `$x` variable: `[int]$x`. Also, use the proper syntax in you `Write-Output`; even though it works, it should be avoided.

Comment: I have tried both `$someHash.[int]$x` and `$someHash[[int]$x]` and it is the same result as what I posted. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: `[int]$x = Read-Host "enter 1,2,3"` otherwise you'd have to use it in a *grouping* operator to expand the value properly:`$var[([int]$x)]`

Comment: Or use _string keys_ (`'1' = ...`) instead of _int keys_ :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I tried using `''` and `""` same outcome.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I tried grouping, and all the casing as noted in my edit, the same outcome.

Comment: I forgot to add a write-out... My bad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *string keys* you won't have a need to convert the result of `Read-Host` to *int*.

**Note**, if below doesn't work, it's most likely because `$x` was type constrained before (`[int]$x`), use `Remove-Variable x` or restart your PowerShell session.

```
$someHash =
@{
    '1' = "one";
    '2' = "two";
    '3' = "three"
}
$x = Read-Host "enter 1,2,3"
$someHash[$x] # => Works (Recommended)
$someHash.$x  # => Works
```

Using *int keys* you would need to type constrain the result of `Read-Host` to *int*:

```
$someHash =
@{
    1 = "one";
    2 = "two";
    3 = "three"
}
[int]$x = Read-Host "enter 1,2,3"
$someHash[$x] # => Works (Recommended)
$someHash.$x  # => Works
```